# Should I continue with Knowledge Transition when I have some other plans for my own?

Tags: job-offer, career-development

In my current company I am being given KT(Knowledge Transition) for a new project. The guy who's giving me KT is supposed to leave in a little over the month and he's handing over the work. I have already attended 3 sessions.

My dilemma is that I already received a Letter of Intent from one of the reputed companies and the package offered is much better.I have accepted the offer but I am yet to receive the final offer letter.

Should I let my manager know about this or continue with the KT and tell once I've the offer letter in hand? I am afraid by that time, the KT would've progressed further and that would be loss of time and resource for the new project team

Answer (score 7):

Until you have a formal offer agreed and in place with the other company continue on at your existing job as if you intend to stay.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this a poster at the top of this board, it comes up so often.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the advice to carry on with the job as if you intend to stay unless and until you have a formal agreement.

One approach to minimize the damage to your current employer would be to suggest that, to improve the bus factor, another person should also participate in the KT, so that you have two people learning. That would be a good plan regardless of whether you stay or go.